# implement the following tables using PROLOG

Tags: prolog

please kindly help me to solve these tables as follows

```
product id     product name     quantity     unit price
   P01         Processor        50           8500
   P02         Hard Disk        50           4500
   P03         RAM              50           2500



Customer ID     Customer Name              Address
    C001        Saman Kumara               Galle Rd, Colombo 3
    C002        Gamini Silva               No 23,Nugegoda
    C003        Samantha Perera            Nawela Road,Nugegoda



Sales ID        Customer ID         Product ID  Quantity
    S01         C001                P01         10
    S02         C001                P02         5
    S03         C001                P03         3
    S04         C002                P01         2
```

Comment: What does "solve these tables" mean? You should read [ask].

Comment: actually i wrote as it is question,it says only this,i am beginner for this all so need help from you

Comment: it need to implement these tables in prolog

Comment: What do you mean by "implement these tables"? Is this homework? Can you provide more detail?

Comment: after implement,create prolog rules called addprodcut/ 0,addcustomer/0 and addsales/0 in order ti add new product,Customer and Sales, Respectively by using the keyboard

Comment: Can you please provide the entire requirement, as given to you by your teacher, in the question? Right now, what you're asking isn't making a lot of sense to me.

Answer (score 1):

you should introduce [extensional predicates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extensional_and_intensional_definitions) for each entity (table) as Prolog facts:

```erlang
% product(product_id, product_name, quantity, unit_price)
product('P01','Processor', 50,8500).
product('P02','Hard Disk', 50,4500).
product('P03','RAM',       50,2500).

etc etc
```

and then concentrate on the queries required to complete your assignment.

Comment: That should be "extensional" according to hyperlink given

Comment: @frayser: you're right, thanks, will correct my silly answer...

Comment: You can use a `library(csv)` to process the rows, rather than having to hand-edit the data into Prolog syntax.